# how to add custom checkboxes in infusionsoft?

Tags: checkbox, infusionsoft

I am trying to add custom checkbox in Infusionsoft.

But in the contact form there is no any option to choose field type to checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in infusionsoft. You cant create custome checkboxes.